# iPhone CATextLayer (QuartzCore framework) linking issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, frameworks, core-animation

I have the following code:

```
CATextLayer *test = [CATextLayer layer];
test.string = summary;
test.wrapped = YES;
//test.truncationMode = kCATruncationEnd;
//test.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentJustified;
test.frame = s;
[test drawInContext:context];
```

I import the  framework and link against it, however when it links I get the following error:

> ld: warning: in
>   /Users/ryansully/Desktop/AppName/Project/1/AppName/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore,
>   missing required architecture i386 in
>   file Undefined symbols:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CATextLayer",
>   referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref-to-CATextLayer in StoriesCell.o ld: symbol(s) not found
>   collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

This is for an iOS project. I get this error in both XCode 3.2.3 and XCode 4 DP2.

Comment: Are you sure you're importing QuartzCore.framework, and you have `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` in your code?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure. I checked this multiple times as per direction by IRC :P

Comment: Tried creating a new project and putting it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out XCode 4 is still buggy and can't add Frameworks appropriately. The issue was solved by opening the project in XCode 3, removing + readding the framework, then compiling.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I resolved it by adding the framework somewhere in the project properties.

In the project properties (in the Project Navigator in the left of XCode interface, click on the project): Targets/[your project's name]/Build Phases/Link Binary With Librairies.

Then add QuartzCore.h (there is a "+" button at the bottom of the list).

Comment: +1 for actually providing steps on how to add QuartzFramework. I knew what the issue was but didn't know how to add the framework itself so thanks for that! :)